# How can I view raw image data in sublime text

Tags: sublimetext

Build 3059 of Sublime Text added image previews. Now when I open an image I can no longer see the raw data. Is there a way to turn this "feature" off?

I'm working with reading/writing EXIF data and it was really useful to be able to dive in and see what was really there. Sublime is a text editor after all.

Comment: Did you find something ? I'm facing the same problem. I asked the plugin "HexViewer" to do something about it on [github](https://github.com/facelessuser/HexViewer/issues/22).

Comment: No solution yet sorry.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a bit clumsy but you can rename the file to .txt and Sublime will display the raw data.